# Passing strings with Single Qoute from MVC Razor to JavaScript

Tags: javascript, asp.net-mvc, razor, viewbag

This seems so simple it's embarrassing. However, the first question is when passing a value from the new ViewBag in MVC 3.0 (Razor) into a JavaScript block, is this the correct way to do it? And more importantly, where and how do you apply the proper string replacement code to prevent a single quote from becoming &#39 as in the resultant alert below?

Adding this into a single script block:

```
alert('@ViewBag.str')   // "Hi, how's it going?"
```

Results in the following alert:

[image]

Answer (score 40, accepted):

Razor will HTML encode everything, so to prevent the ' from being encoded to `&#39;`, you can  use

```
alert('@Html.Raw(ViewBag.str)');
```

However, now you've got an actual ' in the middle of your string which causes a javascript error.  To get around this, you can either wrap the alert string in double quotes (instead of single quotes), or escape the ' character.  So, in your controller you would have

```
ViewBag.str = "Hi, how\\'s it going?";
```

Comment: If you'd rather not have to re-escape strings, try `@Html.Raw(String.Format("var str = \"{0}"\", ViewBag.str)` followed by `alert(str);`

Comment: Isn't this a huge risk for script injection?

Answer (score 0):

Another solution to use JSON string:

C#

```
ViewBag.str = "[{\"Text\":\"Hi, how's it going?\"}]";
```

Javascript

```
var j = @Html.Raw(ViewBag.str);
alert (j[0].Text);
```