# Howto get 'real' single quotes

Tags: javascript, asp.net, code-behind, quotes

I have an asp.net web page.

Is there a possibility to just get 'real' single quotes client side?

Server side:

```
this.Attributes["onclick"] = "$('#button').click();";
```

Client side:

```
onclick="$(&amp;#39;#button&amp;#39;).click();"
```

gives an error.

Alert works just fine, i.e. Client side:

```
onclick="alert(&amp;#39;hello#amp;39;);".
```

Seems like I need 'real' single quotes to work with jQuery.

Comment: possible duplicate of [ASP.NET single quotes are converted to &#39;](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/3013912/asp-net-single-quotes-are-converted-to-39)

Comment: dup of http://stackoverflow.com/questions/3013912/asp-net-single-quotes-are-converted-to-39

Comment: Jason: Yes, I made those conclusions already. I don't like the idea to use html elements in the source file and use runat=server. It will also become a problem when adding dynamic controls to a page.
I know this change has to do with securtiy (XSS), but it seems just like a bug if you ask me. Seems like MS did not thoroughly tested cases like above or they need start loving js some more ;)

Comment: Stark that's the same link as the one Jason posted

Comment: See if [this](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/5749590/passing-strings-with-single-qoute-from-mvc-razor-to-javascript) helps any.

Comment: ataddeini - As far as I know I can't use Html.Raw in standard asp.net and escaping doesn't work, it always comes up with &amp;#39; (seems like a bug).

Comment: the semicolons and the apostrophes are at war.

Answer (score 1):

Is this standard ASP.NET, or ASP.NET MVC? It appears that the output is being escaped, but without sample code or more details I cannot be certain.

Your code example of

```
this.Attributes["onclick"] = "$('#button').click();";
```

How is that rendered from the server? From a control?

**Updated**

This attribute value encoding was introduced in .NET 4.0. If you must you can set the `controlRenderingCompatibilityVersion` in your web.config to "3.5" see [pages Element (ASP.NET Settings Schema)](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/950xf363%28v=VS.100%29.aspx) & [PagesSection.ControlRenderingCompatibilityVersion Property](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.web.configuration.pagessection.controlrenderingcompatibilityversion.aspx).

Could you (instead of placing the onclick logic directly in the attribute value) record the function elsewhere and set the function name as the onclick value? Or register the click handler client side using jQuery?

Comment: Standard ASP.NET. Rendered in page code behind (prerender) for a hyperlink (HyperLink control on page).

Comment: Thanks, I've created a sample app and can reproduce your issue, and after a quick google search I see you are not alone, plenty of others are having the same issue after upgrading to .NET 4.0. I've updated my answer with a few suggestions.

Comment: Thx Marc. Yes, I made a jQuery ready function to assign the click handler. In this case it will do, I wonder what to do when things are dynamic ...

Comment: You could use the `ClientScriptManager` as shown here: http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/btf44dc9.aspx

Comment: Thanks Marc. I know the ClientScriptBlocks. If you ask me that's kind of huge for something small I am trying to accomplish ;)

Comment: True enough :) p.s if you found my answer useful at all I wouldn't mind an upvote ;)